# Nim macro parameters

Tags: macros, nim-lang

here' a code I want to compile:

```
macro defineSomething(amount:expr):stmt=
   var amountInt = intVal(amount).int
   # Boring staff

defineSomething(42);
```

It works perfectly. I have all I want inside my macro I can operate staff in my own way.

But then I think, that, It would be better to remove magic number to some const settings:

```
const MAGIC_AMOUNT:int = 42

# Whole lot of strings
defineSomething(MAGIC_AMOUNT)
```

This code fails. Because `MAGIC_AMOUNT` literally is not integer value unlike `42` magic number.

So, how to get my variable value inside the macros in nim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions are [untyped](http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#untyped). Since you really want to get integers you can specify the parameter to be [typed](http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#typed) and then this should compile:

```
import macros

macro defineSomething(amount: typed):stmt=
  echo getType(amount)
  var amountInt = intVal(amount).int
  echo "Hey ", amount_int

const MAGIC_AMOUNT = 42
defineSomething(43)
defineSomething(MAGIC_AMOUNT)
```

Or just use a normal `int` as the parameter type unless you want to be passed other types as well to `case` on the parameter's [kind](http://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#kind,NimNode) inside your macro.

Comment: Oh, I just tried `macro defSomething(amount:int):stmt=` and it worked with `amount.intVal.int`. So, It helped.

Answer (score 4):

By default, macros will receive AST expressions and not values. If your macro needs to work with concrete values, you need to use static parameters:

```
macro defineSomething(amount: static[int]): stmt=
  echo "int value: ", amount + 100

const MAGIC_AMOUNT = 42

defineSomething(43)
defineSomething(MAGIC_AMOUNT)
```

This will print at compile-time:

```
int value: 143
int value: 142
```